# Python, tkinter: Use multiprocessing.Pool() in a class instance, get new data from pool in a function that runs every second

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm still struggling to get a thread pool working inside a class instance. In a file we'll call `test.py` I have the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def exec(self):
        pool = mp.Pool()
        result = pool.map(self.thread, range(0, 4))
        for r in result:
            print(r)

    def thread(self, i):
        return i * 2
```

In `init.py` I then have:

```
import test

t = test.Test()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t.exec()
```

This works successfully: When I run `init.py` from a console the threads execute and return the doubled numbers. The problem is that I want to make my thread pool a class property, not a local variable. The correct content of `test.py` is thus supposed to be:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = mp.Pool()

    def exec(self):
        result = self.pool.map(self.thread, range(0, 4))
        for r in result:
            print(r)

    def thread(self, i):
        return i * 2
```

But this returns the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled
```

I'm not trying to pass the pool between processes: The class instance of `Test` calling the pool is supposed to remain on the main thread only, hence why it's executed under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` check. I do however want the pool to be a property of `self` so it can be reused, otherwise I have to create a new pool each time `exec` is called.

`exec` is meant to be called repeatedly every 1 second and use the thread pool to get new data each time. In the full code I use `tkinter` so `self.root.after(1000, self.exec)` is used after `init.py` initially activates this function which is then meant to reschedule itself and run repeatedly: `root.after` is the only way I'm aware of without the main loop of TK blocking my other loop from running. Here's a full view of what `test.py` is supposed to look like if we also take tkinter into account, please let me know how that would need to be rewritten to work.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tkinter as tk

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = mp.Pool()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def exec(self):
        result = self.pool.map(self.thread, range(0, 4))
        for r in result:
            print(r)
        self.root.after(1000, self.exec)

    def thread(self, i):
        return i * 2
```

Comment: I passed by a similar question a few days ago [Can I submit the task to ProcessPoolExecutor in "class instance"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591484/can-i-submit-the-task-to-processpoolexecutor-in-class-instance), you also don't want to be serializing tkinter stuff as the result is unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you: I'll take a closer look later when I have more time. For now I wanted to add: I'm perfectly okay with splitting the threaded function into its own class, that might even be more ideal. I just want to not rely on globals (everything should be in a class instance) whereas the pool should be set once and be reusable from the base class (main thread) since destroying then creating new pools every # milliseconds sounds suboptimal and might even upset the some OS'es, and since it's by far what I need the `pool.map()` function should be used to wait until all data has been received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. The trick was to use two classes, main class issues the thread pool to the secondary class which then uses it to pipe in results from a local function. Something among the following lines worked out for me, rewritten as a representation since my final result diverged a bit already... let me know if you think it can be further improved.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def exec(self, pool):
        return pool.map(self.thread, range(0, 4))

    def thread(self, i):
        return i * 2

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = mp.Pool()
        self.other = Test1()

    def obtain(self):
        return self.other.exec(self.pool)

t = Test2()
t.obtain()
```